# How to have multiple service.xml in a single plugin

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

#### I have

1. Single project - Test
2. Multiple portlets in this project like - Test01, Test02, Test03.

#### I want to

1. have services generated through service-builder.
2. have services for different portlet to reside in different packages, like for liferay we have `service.xml`s as `<service-builder package-path="com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary">` and

#### Question

1. Is there a way I can have multiple service.xml files for each portlet's services.
2. If I can have multiple service.xml files then can I have the `LocalService` classes generated for different portlet in different packages like:

   1. For `Test01`: com.prakash.test.one.Test01LocalService
   2. For `Test02`: com.prakash.test.two.Test02LocalService
   3. For `Test03`: com.prakash.test.three.Test03LocalService

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think we can do it using <service-builder-import file="demo.xml"></service-builder-import>.We can create one service.xml file and import all other xml file in it.There is one more thread here which help http://www.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/23283488

Comment: Or we can have multiple service.xml also. provided that the package name in both of them is different.

Comment: using `<service-builder-import file="demo.xml">` we can only have one package-path specified in the `service.xml` and it does not work for including service.xmls. So different package-path does not work.

Comment: Are all portlets Test01, Test02 & Test03 inside same context (in other words, same .war file ?) Also, are you using Ant or maven to run service builder ?

Comment: I mentioned `2. Multiple portlets in this project like - Test01, Test02, Test03.`, so yes they are in the same context. I am using ANT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one solution looking at the source code of Liferay. It would require Liferay IDE.

1. We can have multiple `service.xml` in there respective packages like `com/prakash/test/one/service.xml`, `com/prakash/test/two/service.xml` etc.
2. Then we can build each `service.xml` individually.
3. We can build the service by opening the `service.xml` in Liferay IDE. Then clicking the top-right corner icon to build the service or using shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.
4. It builds the services in their respective packages
5. Also includes the consolidated `*service.jar` for the project in `WEB-INF/lib/` as usual.

Hope this helps somebody.